# Preposition usage

Tags: tenses

Should it be "the snake moved THROUGH the grass" or the snake "moved IN the grass" ?I have seen "moved in the grass" used in some places but I feel like it depends on the density of the grass. Which one's correct ? An explanation would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Without context, I would say "moved through the grass" implies direction, meaning the snake moved purposefully from point A to point B.  To me, "moved in the grass" means that the snake is moving but with no intent on a particular direction.

Both are correct, it just depends on the context.

Comment: One more. Do you think a road goes "through a mountain" or "over a mountain"?

Comment: This one is quite literal and is based on the construction of the road.  If the road is built to rise over the top of the mountain then the road goes "over the mountain."  If the road is tunneled through the mountain or if part of the mountain is cut to allow for the road then the road goes "through the mountain."

Comment: Cool, got it.So there's no set preposition for such instances?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to emphasize.

> The snake moved THROUGH the grass.

This sentence emphasizes the motion of the snake.

> The snake moved IN the grass.

This sentence emphasizes the location of the snake.

Why use one or the other? It depends on the context of the sentence. If one didn't know HOW the snake moved, one would likely use the first, and if one didn't know where the snake moved, the second.

> **Q** The snake in the grass did what?
>   **A** It moved through the grass.
>     or
>   **Q** The snake was found. How?
>   **A** It moved in the grass.